# Downloading data from socket servers doesn't work good

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, client, node-modules

I have written socket client which connets with multiple socket servers. Ips and ports are stored in .json file. Client is sending message, then gets responses, which are stored in an array. The problem is that responses are changing their order.

```
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 10000;
const net = require('net')
let adresses = require('./ips.json')
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
let data = ''
let object = {Scales: []}
let weights = []
let units = []
let i = 0;
let temp1 = {}

adresses.ips.forEach(ip => {
    const client = new net.Socket()
    client.connect(ip.port, ip.ip, () => {
        console.log('connected')
        setInterval(() => {
            client.write('SIA\r\n')
        }, 200)
        client.on('data', (result) => {
            data = result.toString().trim()
            weights[0] = data.slice(5, 15).replace(/\s+/g, '')
            units[0] = data.slice(15, 19).replace(/\s+/g, '')
            weights[1] = data.slice(25, 35).replace(/\s+/g, '')
            units[1] = data.slice(35, 39).replace(/\s+/g, '')
            weights[2] = data.slice(45, 55).replace(/\s+/g, '')
            units[2] = data.slice(55, 59).replace(/\s+/g, '')
            weights[3] = data.slice(65, 75).replace(/\s+/g, '')
            units[3] = data.slice(75, 79).replace(/\s+/g, '')
            temp1 = {
                id: i,
                Weighnings: [
                    {id: 1, weight: weights[0], unit: units[0]},
                    {id: 2, weight: weights[1], unit: units[1]},
                    {id: 3, weight: weights[2], unit: units[2]},
                    {id: 4, weight: weights[3], unit: units[3]}
                ]
            }
            object.Scales[i] = temp1
            if (i === adresses.ips.length-1) {
                i = 0
            } else {
                i++
            }
            client.on('error', (err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
            client.on('close', () => {
                console.log('conn closed')
            })
        })
    })
})

const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/db', (req, res) => {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    res.send(JSON.stringify(object))
    res.end()
})

app.listen(1000, () => {
    console.log('App is running on port 1000')
});
```

I tried to add some loops or smthng but it didn't worked.